# How to solve node package manager errors with related to package node-gyp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, npm-install

I know this question has been answered [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457761/how-to-solve-node-gyp-rebuild-issue-on-windows-10) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35664985/node-gyp-rebuild-error-while-installing-node-modules).
But I am unable to solve this situation with the method provided.After npm install i got these error tried to rebuild the node-gyp to no gain.
Node =v7.2.0
Npm = 3.10.9

```
C:\Users\Pirate\Desktop\Nem\nem_find\node_modules\buffertools>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Pira
te\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v7.2.0\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (nod
e "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036:
The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project p
roperty pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\Pirate\Desktop\Nem\nem_find\node_modules\buffertools\build\buffertools.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Pirate\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v7.2.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\b
uild.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Pirate\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v7.2.0\\node_modules\\npm\\node_
modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Pirate\Desktop\Nem\nem_find\node_modules\buffertools
gyp ERR! node -v v7.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> node-expat@2.3.15 install C:\Users\Pirate\Desktop\Nem\nem_find\node_modules\node-expat
> node-gyp rebuild
e\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v7.2.0\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node
 "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Platforms\x64\PlatformToolsets\v140\Toolset.targets(36,5): error MSB8036:
The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project p
roperty pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\Pirate\Desktop\Nem\nem_find\node_modules\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\expat.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Pirate\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v7.2.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\b
uild.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Pirate\\AppData\\Roaming\\nvm\\v7.2.0\\node_modules\\npm\\node_
modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Pirate\Desktop\Nem\nem_find\node_modules\node-expat
gyp ERR! node -v v7.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN kue-scheduler@0.1.1 requires a peer of async@^0.9.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN kue-scheduler@0.1.1 requires a peer of lodash@^3.6.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: buffertools@2.1.4 (node_modules\buffertools):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: buffertools@2.1.4 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE  


npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.15 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Pirate\Desktop\Nem\nem_find\npm-debug.log
```

**/
New responses after npm install..

```
npm ERR! node-expat@2.3.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.3.15 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-expat
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\users\pirate\desktop\nem\backup\nem_find\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/629#issuecomment-153196245

Comment: Have you tried updating npm to 4.0.5? My coworker had issues that seed to disappear, but not sure if it will help your situation.

Comment: yes everything.

Comment: My advice is to move to mac or Linux, i respect what Microsoft is doing with there cloud and all but on windows they haven't got it yet, it will take them another 10 years to solve the issues of development community. You ask any i mean any developer working with MEAN Django or ROR they will not recommend windows just simply because its not reliable you cannot trust windows.....sad:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a comment on top but It's necessary to let everyone know.It took me only 15 mins to set everything I mean everything on Debian.
 My advice is to move to mac or Linux, I respect what @Microsoft is doing with there cloud and all but on windows they haven't got it yet, it will take them another 10 years to solve the issues of development community. You ask any i mean any developer working with MEAN Django or ROR they will not recommend windows just simply because its not reliable you cannot trust windows.....sad:(

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried updgrading npm to v4.x?
npm install npm@latest -g

I had problems with 3.10.6 with shrinkwrap and the **fsevents** package which is Mac Os specific.  If I deleted the **npmshrinkwrap.json** file I could run npm i and it would run fine.  Once I upgraded to v4.0.3 of npm it worked with shrinkwrap.  This all assuming you use shrinkwrap of course.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is related to this:

> The Windows SDK version 8.1 was not found. Install the required
>   version of Windows SDK or change the SDK version in the project p
>   roperty pages or by right-clicking the solution and selecting
>   "Retarget solution".
>   [C:\Users\Pirate\Desktop\Nem\nem_find\node_modules\node-expat\build\deps\libexpat\expat.vcxproj]

You need to [install Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-8-1-sdk) before you can recompile using node-gyp.

Comment: But i have windows 10 64bit

Comment: Ran into similar errors (on Win10/64) and modified VisualStudio  (via Add/Remove programs) to include Windows 8.1 SDKs. I'm not entirely sure that's what fixed my problem - it was awhile back - but possibly worth a try?

Answer (score 1):

Check again into your `package.json` file their is available `node-gyp` module or not with version ID if there is not available then add and again install from `npm`.