# Reactnative: code ELIFECYCLE error When installing expo-cli

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to install expo-cli on **windows 10,** according it's [official site](https://expo.io/learn):

```
>npm install expo-cli --global
```

I got this following error:

```
C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH>npm install expo-cli --global
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.

> @expo/traveling-fastlane-linux@1.11.0 preinstall C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\traveling-fastlane-linux
> node platform.js

Does not seem like WSL enabled on this machine. Download a Linux distro from the Windows Store, run it at least onceand then make sure to run in an admin powershell:
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo-cli -> C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo -> C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js

> dtrace-provider@0.8.8 install C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider
> node-gyp rebuild || node suppress-error.js


C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\dtrace-provider>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.

> iltorb@2.4.4 install C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\iltorb
> node ./scripts/install.js || node-gyp rebuild

info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\95b49f-iltorb-v2.4.4-node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
info found cached prebuild
info unpacking @ C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\95b49f-iltorb-v2.4.4-node-v72-win32-x64.tar.gz
info unpack resolved to C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\iltorb\build\bindings\iltorb.node
info unpack required C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\iltorb\build\bindings\iltorb.node successfully
info install Successfully installed iltorb binary!

> sharp@0.22.1 install C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Using cached C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_libvips\libvips-8.7.4-win32-x64.tar.gz
info sharp Creating C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\sharp\build\Release
info sharp Copying DLLs from C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\sharp\vendor\lib to C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\sharp\build\Release

> core-js@2.6.10 postinstall C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\core-js
> node postinstall || echo "ignore"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

Thank you for installing EJS: built with the Jake JavaScript build tool (https://jakejs.com/)


> envsub@3.1.0 postinstall C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\envsub
> test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push || true

'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'true' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.11.0 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\traveling-fastlane-darwin):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.11.0: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-win32-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-win32-ia32@2.2.8-beta.1: wanted {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-sunos-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-sunos-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"sunos","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-linux-arm):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"linux","arch":"arm"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-freebsd-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"freebsd","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-x64):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-x64@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"x64"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for @expo/ngrok-bin-darwin-ia32@2.2.8: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"ia32"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! envsub@3.1.0 postinstall: `test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push || true`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the envsub@3.1.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tazika.SAFARAYANEH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-01T14_19_42_669Z-debug.log
```

I am using python version:

```
>python --version
Python 3.8.0
```

and node and npm versions:

```
>node --version
v12.13.1

>npm --version
6.12.1
```

I installed **visual studio 2015**, i think is good to know that.
What is your suggestion?

This is [complete error](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zH76jKFRqF/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i fixed my problem after a day trying:

[According this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32457761/how-to-solve-node-gyp-rebuild-issue-on-windows-10)

```
1- Download and install Git SCM
2- Download Visual Studio Community HERE and install a Custom Installation, selecting ONLY the following packages: VISUAL C++, PYTHON TOOLS FOR VISUAL STUDIO and MICROSOFT WEB DEVELOPER TOOLS
3- Download and install Python 2.7.x
4- Register a Environment Variable with name: GYP_MSVS_VERSION with this value: 2015
```

After these installations i think this part is important:

> **postinstall** script of **envsub** depends on built-in **unix shell** commands. So any shell compatible with unix shell should works, like **Git BASH**