# code ELIFECYCLE error When installing expo-cli

Tags: node.js, npm

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

I got this following error:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! envsub@3.1.0 postinstall: `test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push || true`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the envsub@3.1.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-01T12_11_45_118Z-debug.log
```

node and npm versions:

```
node --version
v12.13.1
npm --version
6.12.1
```

I am trying to install expo-cli on windows 10, according it's official site:

> npm install expo-cli --global
>   I got this following error:

43056 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18362
43057 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "expo-cli" "--global"
43058 verbose node v12.13.1
43059 verbose npm  v6.12.1
43060 error code ELIFECYCLE
43061 error errno 1
43062 error envsub@3.1.0 postinstall: `test -d .git && cp gitHookPrePush.sh .git/hooks/pre-push || true`
43062 error Exit status 1
43063 error Failed at the envsub@3.1.0 postinstall script.
43063 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
43064 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
I am using python version:

> python --version
>   Python 3.8.0
>   and node and npm versions:
>
> node --version
>   v12.13.1
>
> npm --version
>   6.12.1
>   **
>   What is your suggestion?

**

Comment: I faced the same issue, instead of running the command on command prompt for windows 10 , try on Git bash as suggested in answer by @JaskaranSingh

Answer (score 19):

just try installing `npm install expo-cli --global` this command on git bash. It worked for me.

Comment: Faced the same issue, running the command on git bash helped me, thanks  !

Comment: This worked .. tried 10 other solutions before, tnx !

Comment: you just saved my life - spent 4 hours to install all possible things that I could :-)

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and the question? I mean the command line. The one who questioned tried npm install expo-cli --global and got the error, and you are telling him to put npm install expo-cli --global and people are saying it helped? I'm lost now

Comment: the difference is of the command prompt, run it in Git Bash command window not in traditional windows command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

[I fixed this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59124830/reactnative-code-elifecycle-error-when-installing-expo-cli/59126514#59126514) :

```
1- Download and install Git SCM
2- Download Visual Studio Community HERE and install a Custom Installation, selecting ONLY the following packages: VISUAL C++, PYTHON TOOLS FOR VISUAL STUDIO and MICROSOFT WEB DEVELOPER TOOLS
3- Download and install Python 2.7.x
4- Register a Environment Variable with name: GYP_MSVS_VERSION with this value: 2015
```

After these installations i think this part is important:

> **postinstall** script of **envsub** depends on built-in **unix shell** commands. So any shell compatible with unix shell should works, like **Git BASH**

So run `npm install expo-cli --global` after above installation  on `Git BASH`